# python fabric hangs on a bashscript will not return an object

Tags: python, ssh, fabric

i have a script that will hang the fabric connection 
here is my function

```
c=Connection(host=address , user=host_user, port=22,connect_kwargs = {'key_filename':key_filename1} )
            scriptfile=open(script)
            output=c.run(scriptfile.read(),hide=True)
            print(output.stdout)
```

the script i have will run servers as processes:

```
if [ "$iface" != "lo" ] ; then

           iperf3 -s -B 192.168.$x.$base -p 500$x &

           x=$((x+1))
fi
```

how can i solve this ???

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51897382/13317 probably

Comment: thx but i actually try that but still same